# jQuery .click keeps adding to the event, rather than replacing it

Tags: jquery, click

I have [the following code block](http://jsfiddle.net/2WV5E/):

```
function testJQueryClick(){
     $('#button2').click(function(){ alert ('Debug'); return false; });       
}
```

When I call the function once (and then click on button 2), I get the expected alert. When I call the same function a second time and then click button 2, I get two alerts, third time I get three, etc. jQuery seems to be appending the `.click` event each time, rather than replacing it.

I would expect that the `.click` handler to be *replaced* each time I call it. I can't find anything in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/) that either confirms this as the expected behaviour, or not.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You'll want to first call `off` the get rid of the old event listener:

```
function testJQueryClick () {
    $('#button2').off('click').on('click', function () {
        alert ('Debug');

        return false;
    });      
}
```

[See it in the Pen in action](http://codepen.io/JosephSilber/pen/MpJNxZ?editors=1010).

Comment: `unbind` is deprecated as of jQuery 3 - you should use `off` instead

Answer (score 4):

Check out the documentation for the bind() method at http://api.jquery.com/bind/. The event binding method's such as "click()", "focus()", etc... are just shortcuts for bind(*eventtype*) so reading the bind() docs will give you insight into how all of the event binds work.  I think the bit that pertains to your specific issue is:

"When an event reaches an element, all handlers bound to that event type for the element are fired."

Meaning if you bind the handler "function(){ alert ('Debug'); return false; }" to the click event 5 times, all 5 will execute.

As a sidenote, the preferred and more modern way to bind to an onclick handler is to completely bypass the "onclick" attribute of a link and perform all your binds on DOM load using jQuery. Here's an example that uses more modern binds and also utilizes the trigger() method to fire the #button2 click handler when #button1 is clicked (which is what I think you were trying to achieve in your example):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button2').click(function(){ alert ('Debug'); return false; });  // Bind alert to #button2 click
    $('#button1').click(testJQueryClick);                                           // Bind testJQueryClick() to #button1 click
});

function testJQueryClick(e) {
    $('#button2').trigger('click'); // Trigger #button2 click handler
}
```

Answer (score 2):

while binding an event jquery does not consider what events are already bound on the control it just binds one more event..

unbind eg:

```
$('selector').unbind("eventType");
```

you could use the `unbind` API to remove the bound event first or if its the same click event handler but you are calling it multiple times since a new control with the same selector has been inserted to the dom then you should probably look at using the `live` api..

Hope tihs helps..

Answer (score 1):

As previously noted you need to remove old click handlers before you add the new one if you want to replace it.

As of jQuery 1.7 the preferred way is to use [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/). (`unbind` is deprecated as of jQuery 3)

For example:

```
function testJQueryClick(){
    $('#button2').off('click').click(function(){alert ('Debug'); return false;});       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because every time you are assigning a new click handler. It should just be this:

```
$('#button2').click(function(){ alert ('Debug'); return false; });
```

After the document loads of course.

Comment: This was just an example, I actually wanted to replace the onClick function of an object based on something else you've clicked elsewhere on the page, and they might toggle between the available options, and each time they toggled it was appending.